# parsing string in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bunch of `C++` files in a directory called `src`. I needed to find all the files that have `*Test.cc`, but without the `.cc` file type, so it would just be `[filename]Test`.
I currently have:

```
  1 FILES=./src/*Test.cc
  2 
  3 for f in $FILES
  4     do
  5         echo "processing $f"
  6 done
```

so I only need the name of the file, without `./src/` and without `.cc`.  For example, the above script would produce:

```
processing ./src/UtilTest.cc
```

And I only need `UtilTest`. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

Inserting this line between your lines 4 and 5 will cause your bash snippet to produce the desired output:

```
f=$(basename $f .cc)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish that with this one liner commands:

First is storing it in a file for reference:

```
find ./src/ -name *Test.cc | tee samp.txt
```

Then printing it or it depends on what you want do with the file:

```
cat samp.txt | while read i; do echo `basename $i .cc`; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you another option: for later versions of bash (not sure anymore which version), you can use arrays and string manipulation:

```
files=(.src/*Test.cc)      # create bash array (space-separated)

for f in ${files[@]##./}   # loop through array, stripping leading path 
do 
     echo ${f%%.*}         # f is now array element; strip its extension
done
```

Obviously, as in your own example, when the file name contains spaces or has multiple extentions (e.g., `Your File Test.cc.hpp`), there will be problems.

Anyway, this sidesteps the call to `basename` and does not require a temp file, as in the other two answers; the only downside is its limited portability due to bash version requirements.